# How do I make a now playing bar like in media player apps in iOS with XCode?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6, uistoryboard

I am making a media player app. I have UITableViewControllers that are embedded in Navigation Controller. I would like to somehow make a view that would overlay potentially multiple (2?) of these tableviewcontrollers (one that shows the user's playlists, and the next would show the tracks in the playlist), but only at the bottom, like a now playing bar in (e.g.) Spotify's iOS app (as in the left bottom side of this

[image]

or as in this

[image]

I have tried to drag a Container View into my Navigation controller (in which my TableViewCell is embedded), but it won't let me drop it there.

It looks like I can drag the Container View into my TableView, but then how would it remain there when i navigate between tableviews?

Trying to follow @Rintaro's suggestion, but I'm a little new to XCode. How did you do this? So I made a single view application, i added a container view to the first VC, it's imm drawing it somewhere else in the storyboard, but i can't figure out how to tell that view that it's a navigation controller. also, as soon as i add a second container to the first VC and tried to size it, the first container disappears! It is still listed in the hierarchy on the left, and still has an arrow pointing out of it, but the view controller that was added and was being pointed to is also invisible?!

[image]

[image]

UPDATE: This works very well, but it has a problem with orientation changes. how can i make this work in both orientations? (I hypothesize that it currently positions the "nowplaying view" off screen when the orientation changes).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Basically**, view hierarchy like that is constructed like this:

[image: screenshot]

Using two "Container View" in initial view controller, one for Navigation Controller, one for "Now Playing Bar" view controller.

ADDED:

"Main Container View Controller" would be your own `UIViewController` subclass. It will have responsibility to show/hide "Now Playing Bar".

---

Workaround for Interface Builder strange behaviors.

You can set Auto Layout constraints like following. Maybe you might want to select the view from the left menu.

Note that, you should **uncheck** `Constrain to margins` check box.

Container View for Navigation Controller:

[image: screenshot]

Container View for Now Playing Bar Controller:

[image: screenshot]

And then, `Update Frames` from the menu:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thanks for your post, i've edited my question with my attemp to foloow your answer, seems promising from your screenshot!what kind of view controller is the "Main Container View Controller"? I don't see anything in the object library that has that icon?

Comment: Main controller is the simple UIViewController, which contains 2 UIContainerView's. Good idea.

Comment: @rintaro Do you know why this Now playing view would disappear on orientation change?

Comment: @rintaro how would you implement it in with a tab bar navigation?

Answer (score 2):

If you are manually placing any buttons with absolute coordinates, make sure that you update the coordinates of them when the rotation is changed.

Comment: This seems to be more a comment rather than an actual answer

Comment: I was setting the position of the nowplayingview based on the screen size, but when you rotate, i should then use the transposed dimensions (e.g.screen width to set y position). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need to create a custom UIView class, where you will show this menu. And when you will create it, add it to your view just like here:

```
float y = ROOTVC.view.frame.size.height - 49;
[self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, 320, 49)];
[ROOTVC.view addSubview:self];
[ROOTVC.view bringSubviewToFront:self];
```

Comment: I tried this actually, but it doesn't seem to show. To what VC should it be added as a subview?

Comment: @Michael add it to your root VC - UINavigationController. Try this snippet `#define ROOTVC [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController]`

Answer (score 0):

I would simply add a `nowPlayingView` to the `appDelegate.window` and adjust either:

- The `window.rootController.view` frame to avoid overlapping the `nowPlayingView`.
- If `window.rootController.view` is a `UIScrollView`, adjust its `contentInset.bottom` to avoid overlapping the `nowPlayingView`. You can also use transparency/translucency with this solution.
- Add a dummy toolbar to the controller that will get covered by the `nowPlayingView`.

If your `window.rootController` is a `UINavigationController`, then you have to probably do the above fore each controller you push. The `nowPlayingView` will stay unchanged on top.