# Create the custom UITabBar controller and highlight the selected tab with separator

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, custom-controls, uitabbar

Please find the below screenshot and their specification for tabbar.

1. Display the corner radius to only the top left corner and apply the shadow on it.
2. Apply the curve to the top right corner.
3. Show the selected tab with red font color and show the separator
   underneath.

As I am stuck for the last three days.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: UITabbar cotroller]

Comment: for custom tabbar refer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/48293806/6630644

Comment: For corner radious -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview

Comment: See this app-> https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/luxe-radio/id1073120504?mt=8

Comment: Thanks, @SPatel I had reviewed it but I thought for applying the curve to the UITabbar which was not able to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunching` method:-

```
let tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
        let tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage().createSelectionIndicatorFill(fillColor:.red, lineColor:.blue,size: CGSize(width:tabBar.frame.width/CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count), height:tabBar.frame.height), lineWidth: 1.0)
            tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = customColor
        }
```

and make extension of `UIImage`

```
extension UIImage {
    func createSelectionIndicatorFill(fillColor: UIColor,lineColor:UIColor,size: CGSize, lineWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        fillColor.setFill()
        UIRectFill(CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:size.width, height:size.height - lineWidth))

        lineColor.setFill()

        UIRectFill(CGRect(x:0, y:size.height - lineWidth, width:size.width, height:lineWidth))

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Shabbir for your answer but it only satisy to display the separator under the selected tabbar. As I also need to match the same look of UITabbar to attach screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by creating a custom tab bar and add every respect view controller of the tab to add it as child vc with these steps.

1. create a custom view with a view(add buttons and separators as
   subviews). You can achieve the curve of top corners with either UIBezierPath or using the binary image, and manage button and separator behaviors like the color.
2. Add first tab's VC on view did load

   ```
       self.add(asChildViewController: firstViewController)
   ```
3. And add/remove(show/hide) child view controller while on every button taps like this

   ```
   //MARK: - Add Child View Controller

   private func add(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {

   // Add Child View Controller
   addChildViewController(viewController)

   // Add Child View as Subview
   view.addSubview(viewController.view)

   // Configure Child View
   viewController.view.frame = view.bounds
   viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

   // Notify Child View Controller
   viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
   }



   //MARK: - Remove Child View Controller
   private func remove(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {

   // Notify Child View Controller
   viewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)

   // Remove Child View From Superview
   viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()

   // Notify Child View Controller
   viewController.removeFromParentViewController()
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your idea which is good but for that, I need to maintain a lot of things, As I need to show the UITabbar in each VC, suppose if the user goes from first tab's VC to detail VC then I need to create the View again and display at the bottom.

Comment: No, you have to create a view Contoller like custumTabBarViewController, and in that VC you will manage the tab bar's view(like buttons and curve) and only add and remove the viewControllers as childVC on parentViewController(custumTabBarViewController). You don't have to create tab bar's view(like buttons and curve) everywhere.

Comment: "you have to create a view Contoller like custumTabBarViewController" >> For that I need to manage each VC transition and status of the tab as well as in detail VC also. Result lots of handling and may possible for dublication of code.

Comment: Code duplication for sure is not there, and by using this approach you can achieve curve design.

Comment: by using this approach you can achieve curve design >> Agree but I am looking if it is done by the UITabbar then it's great.