# I want to make a custom tab bar without using tab bar controller

Tags: swift

In this image I put a tab bar on it, and then put tab bar items on it. Then I added this code, but it overlaps the content. The tab bar works properly and all of the content is overlapping. Please help.

[image: example]

```
    import UIKit

    class TabViewController: UIViewController,UITabBarDelegate {
        @IBOutlet weak var tabbar: UITabBar!
        var tabViewController:UIViewController?
        var tbnViewController:UIViewController?
        var membersViewController:UIViewController?
        var profileViewController:UIViewController?
        override func viewDidLoad()    {
            super.viewDidLoad()
         self.tabbar.delegate = self
                      }
        func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
            switch item.tag {
            case 0:
                if tabViewController == nil   {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    tabViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabViewController") as! TabViewController

                        }
       self.view.insertSubview(tabBarController!.view!, belowSubview: self.tabbar)
            case 1:
                if tbnViewController == nil {
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    tbnViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TbnViewController") as! TbnViewController
                               }
         self.view.insertSubview(tbnViewController!.view!, belowSubview: self.tabbar)
               case 2:
                if membersViewController == nil {
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    membersViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MembersViewController") as! MembersViewController
                          }
             self.view.insertSubview(membersViewController!.view!, belowSubview: self.tabbar)
            case 3:
                if profileViewController == nil {
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    profileViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController")
                          }
            self.view.insertSubview(profileViewController!.view!, belowSubview: self.tabbar)
                default:
                break
             }
             }

            }
```

In this image a put a tab bar on it and then put tab bar items on it and put this code but there is a problem in it that it will overlap the content to each other the tab bar works properly and all of the content is overlapping please help it.

Comment: i suggest you to use UITabBarViewController like -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/48293806/6630644

Comment: i am a intern and my senior told me that you have to make it with this so i can't use tabbarviewcontroller

Comment: for that you need to add your controller as child controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are just adding view of sub-controllers to to your custom tab-bar controller view. I would suggest to use the mechanism of adding child view controller to get the benefits of viewController lifecycle. Below is the code snippet:-

```
extension UIViewController {

    func addChildViewController(_ viewController : UIViewController?, forView container: UIView){
        guard let viewController = viewController else { return }
        viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addChildViewController(viewController)
        container.addSubview(viewController.view)
        let childView = viewController.view

        container.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView!, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: container, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
        container.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView!, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: container, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
        container.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView!, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: container, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
        container.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView!, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: container, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
        viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

    func removeChildVC(_ viewController : UIViewController?){

        if let viewController = viewController{
            viewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
            viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Use these methods in your custom tab-bar viewController

Comment: how i put this on my  code  can you give me an example

Comment: Add a UIView in TabViewController and create its IBOutlet(eg. containerView). This will act as a container for all your child viewControllers. In your switch case replace following `self.view.insertSubview(tabBarController!.view!, belowSubview: self.tabbar)` with `addChildViewController(tabViewController, forView: .containerView)`.
Let me know if you face any problem

Comment: it create problem when i click on second  third or fourth tab its work and when i click on first tab again it overlap first tab again on it

Comment: Upload a screenshot of overlapped viewController

Comment: sir i fix the problem tks for your suggestion