# Making bends and curves in the tab bar using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

Hello all I want to make a bend in the middle of the tab bar just like in this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYgtc.png)

Comment: You might want to learn about `UIBezierPath`, but you need to learn how to draw it yourself.

Comment: Ok I will check about that thanks @Larme

Comment: as @Larme said you can use `UIBezierPath` and `CAShapeLayer`... try from your end. if you can't then let us know will help

Comment: @m.n Did you find solution?

Comment: @RajanSingh I used UIBezierPath it was hard to learn but it made me close to what I need
check this link it really helped me
https://www.appcoda.com/bezier-paths-introduction/

Comment: @m.n can you help? can you share your tab bar code it will be very helpful and also save my time.

Comment: @RajanSingh
https://pastebin.com/k1feLNaP

Comment: @m.n thank you for your help let me check and update you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SwiftUI` to custom-build a curved tab bar.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6W2vuwWTAU4) is a YouTube link with sample code on how to do it.

If you would like to use `UIKit`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55042538/how-to-set-top-left-and-right-corner-radius-with-desired-drop-shadow-in-uitabbar) is a link with sample code on how to do it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can I put SwiftUI code inside UIKit code?
I know that I can use UIKit in SwiftUI but not the other way.

Comment: @m.n They should work together, but in case they don't, I have added a new link to my answer! Hope it helps!