# How to make Custom TabBar?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, tabbar

[image]

I have to customize the tab bar like the picture above. However, I don't know how to customize this point because the name of the item should appear only when the tab bar is selected, and the name of the item should not appear if it is not selected. Please help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48293806/6630644

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example, it was written with two items. 
You can branch to the `tag` depending on the selected item in `didSelect()` method. 
In `viewWillAppear()`, I wrote the title of first item because the first item is selected when the app is first launched. (initialization)

I hope my answer is helpful to you.

***TabBarController.swift***

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.delegate = self
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
    
        //Setting the UITabBarItem
        
        let tab1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewController")
        let tab1BarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "home", image: UIImage(systemName: "seal"), selectedImage: UIImage(systemName: "seal.fill"))
        tab1.tabBarItem = tab1BarItem
        tab1.tabBarItem.tag = 0
        
        let tab2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "SearchViewController")
        let tab2BarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "", image: UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.seal"), selectedImage: UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.seal.fill"))
        tab2.tabBarItem = tab2BarItem
        tab2.tabBarItem.tag = 1
        
        self.viewControllers = [tab1, tab2]
    }
    

    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        
        if item.tag == 0 { // tab1(home)
            item.title = "home"
            tabBar.items?[1].title = ""
        }
        
        if item.tag == 1 { // tab2(search)
            item.title = "search"
            tabBar.items?[0].title = ""
        }
    }
    
}
```

**Preview**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things

1-  To make the the selected tab color green

```
tabController.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.green
```

2- When item is selected listen for `UITabBarControllerDelegate` and assign items with `text` set to `""` for every unselected item

```
tabController.tabBar.items = [] // set all items
```

Comment: UITabBarControllerDelegate is tabBar(_:didBeginCustomizing:) this.. ??

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate/1621173-tabbarcontroller or   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbardelegate/1623463-tabbar

Comment: Is there any way to erase item text other than tabbar's image initially?

Comment: reinit it again with text "" and same image for that item