# How to create custom curved iOS UITabBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, uibezierpath, bezier

So this is the navigation my designer made for our project. Height of the TabBar is 70.

[image: curved iOS tab bar]

What I have tried so far.
My attempt was based on tutorial from Philipp Weiss.

https://betterprogramming.pub/draw-a-custom-ios-tabbar-shape-27d298a7f4fa

Its based on idea of creating custom IBDesignable UITabBar class and overriding draw method.

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomizedTabBar: UITabBar {

    private var shapeLayer: CALayer?
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.addShape()
    }

    private func addShape() {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = createPath()
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueMenu2.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blueMenu2.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0

        if let oldShapeLayer = self.shapeLayer {
            self.layer.replaceSublayer(oldShapeLayer, with: shapeLayer)
        } else {
            self.layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, at: 0)
        }

        self.shapeLayer = shapeLayer
    }


    func createPath() -> CGPath {

        let height: CGFloat = 37.0
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let centerWidth = self.frame.width / 2

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)) // start top left
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - height * 2), y: 0)) // the beginning of the trough

        // first curve down
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: centerWidth, y: height),
                      controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - 30), y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: centerWidth - 35, y: height))
        // second curve up
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth + height * 2), y: 0),
                      controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: centerWidth + 35, y: height), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth + 30), y: 0))

        // complete the rect
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height))
        path.close()

        return path.cgPath
    }
```

I was trying to edit bezier path to reach my goal but with no success.
I am not sure if this approach can work for this specific TabBar design.

Setting height of navigation to 70 was without problem.

```
@IBInspectable var height: CGFloat = 70

    override open func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
            guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else {
                return super.sizeThatFits(size)
            }
            var sizeThatFits = super.sizeThatFits(size)
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                sizeThatFits.height = height + window.safeAreaInsets.bottom
            } else {
                sizeThatFits.height = height
            }
            return sizeThatFits
        }
```

How can I create this curved TabBar?

Do u know how to make similar shape just by using bezier curves?

Comment: My suggestion is to use custom UIView as a tabbar https://stackoverflow.com/a/48293806/6630644

https://apps.apple.com/au/app/togness-slide-show-maker/id1528833797

Comment: So make TabBar transparent.
Put custom curved UIView above transparent TabBar.

And maybe would be great it there is possibility to position TabBar items (buttons) above curved UIView.

Comment: But I think it is not possible to position TabBar items above cusom UIView.

Comment: Forget UITabBar you need to handle your items inside custom view. And its possible just check the second link i did same thing

Comment: You might consider adding a second window to serve as the tab bar, here's an article that helped me understand the approach. https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/swiftui-windows/

Comment: Extra UIWindow objects mess with the status bar now since they switched to using ViewController based status bar control, it takes the top most window, so I'd avoid using extra UIWindows unless you really need to; and this can be handled without one.

Comment: @kostik - are you happy with your `CustomizedTabBar` but you just need a `UIBezierPath` to get that look?

Comment: @DonMag Yes solution with customized UIBezierPath would be probably best solution for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a `UIBezierPath` for your desired shape...

[image]

- move to 1
- add 90° clockwise arc with center c1
- add line to 2
- add 90° clockwise arc with center c2
- add 180° counter-clockwise arc with center c3
- add 90° clockwise arc with center c4
- add line to 3
- add 90° clockwise arc with center c5
- add line to 4
- add 90° clockwise arc with center c6
- add line to 5
- add 90° clockwise arc with center c7
- close path

Here is some sample code - it's a `UIView` subclass, with all the path elements in `layoutSubviews()`:

```
class TabBarShapeView: UIView {
    var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAShapeLayer.self
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        shapeLayer = self.layer as? CAShapeLayer
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        let middleRad: CGFloat = bounds.height - 10.0
        
        let cornerRad: CGFloat = 12.0
        
        let pth = UIBezierPath()
        
        let topLeftC: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.minX + cornerRad, y: bounds.minY + cornerRad)
        let topRightC: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX - cornerRad, y: bounds.minY + cornerRad)
        let botRightC: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX - cornerRad, y: bounds.maxY - cornerRad)
        let botLeftC: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.minX + cornerRad, y: bounds.maxY - cornerRad)

        var pt: CGPoint!

        // 1
        pt = CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY + cornerRad)
        pth.move(to: pt)
        
        // c1
        pth.addArc(withCenter: topLeftC, radius: cornerRad, startAngle: .pi * 1.0, endAngle: .pi * 1.5, clockwise: true)

        // 2
        pt = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX - middleRad, y: bounds.minY)
        pth.addLine(to: pt)

        // c2
        pt.y += middleRad * 0.5
        pth.addArc(withCenter: pt, radius: middleRad * 0.5, startAngle: -.pi * 0.5, endAngle: 0.0, clockwise: true)
        
        // c3
        pt.x += middleRad * 1.0
        pth.addArc(withCenter: pt, radius: middleRad * 0.5, startAngle: .pi * 1.0, endAngle: 0.0, clockwise: false)
        
        // c4
        pt.x += middleRad * 1.0
        pth.addArc(withCenter: pt, radius: middleRad * 0.5, startAngle: .pi * 1.0, endAngle: .pi * 1.5, clockwise: true)

        // 3
        pt = CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX - cornerRad, y: bounds.minY)
        pth.addLine(to: pt)

        // c5
        pth.addArc(withCenter: topRightC, radius: cornerRad, startAngle: -.pi * 0.5, endAngle: 0.0, clockwise: true)

        // 4
        pt = CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY - cornerRad)
        pth.addLine(to: pt)
        
        // c6
        pth.addArc(withCenter: botRightC, radius: cornerRad, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: .pi * 0.5, clockwise: true)
        
        // 5
        pt = CGPoint(x: bounds.minX + cornerRad, y: bounds.maxY)
        pth.addLine(to: pt)
        
        // c7
        pth.addArc(withCenter: botLeftC, radius: cornerRad, startAngle: .pi * 0.5, endAngle: .pi * 1.0, clockwise: true)
        
        pth.close()
        
        shapeLayer.path = pth.cgPath
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subclass likely isn't working because UITabBar doesn't draw the tab bar itself in `drawRect()`. But makes it from multiple internal sub views.

I'd recommend using a UITabBarController, but hiding the UITabBar itself.

```swift
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = true
```

Then putting your own custom tab bar look alike view at the button of the screen.
Adding `additionalSafeAreaInsets` to make the content move up out of the way of your new view, like they would the real tab bar.

Then just change the tab index yourself on button presses.

```swift
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
```