# Round the corner of a Path

Tags: ios, swiftui

I created a form in SwiftUI. There's one place I can't make round. Can you help?

This is my code :

```
struct BannerShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return Path { path in
            path.move(to: .zero)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 100))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 + 48, y: 0))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 48, y: 0),
                          control1: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 + 80, y: 105),
                          control2: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 80, y: 105))
            path.addLine(to: .zero)
            path.closeSubpath()
        }
    }
}
```

In my preview :

```
struct TabBarBackgroundView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
//    @State static var selectedTabPreview: Int = 0
    
    static var previews: some View {
//        TabBarBackgroundView(selectedTab: $selectedTabPreview)
        
        BannerShape()
            .cornerRadius(15, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight])
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 100)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

The result :

[image: Result]

And I want to round off the two corners near the circle, for the moment it forms a point.

I haven't found anything to do this.

That's what I tried :

```
struct MyShape : Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        
        return Path { path in
            path.move(to: .zero)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 48, y: 0))
            
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 48, y: 10),
                        radius: 10,
                        startAngle: .degrees(-90),
                        endAngle: .degrees(0),
                        clockwise: false)
            
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 + 48, y: 0),
                          control1: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 80, y: 105),
                          control2: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 + 80, y: 105))
                        
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 + 48, y: 10),
                        radius: 10,
                        startAngle: .degrees(-90),
                        endAngle: .degrees(-180),
                        clockwise: true)
            
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 100))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100))
            path.addLine(to: .zero)
            path.closeSubpath()
        }
    }
}
```

And the result...

[image: Result test]

Comment: Take a look at this answer -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/71960280/6257435

Comment: What a perfect answer to this question! (Although in this question there are circles of different radii. The OP may well want corners near the circle with the same rounding radius as the outer 2 rounded corners.)

Comment: @DonMag I've updated the post with what I've tried. One corner is OK but the second is no good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soooo close :)

The `center.x` of your first `.addArc` is at:

```
UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 48
```

and you put the `center.x` of your second `.addArc` at:

```
UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 + 48
```

which is logical.

However, when you add the first arc **with a radius of `10`**, your quad-curve `x` will be starting `10-points` farther (to the right) ... so, you need to end the quad-curve `10-points` shorter (to the left):

```
// need to subtract an additional 10-points
//  for the 10-point radius
path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 + (48 - 10), y: 10),
              control1: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 80, y: 105),
              control2: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 + 80, y: 105))
```

And, your second `.addArc` also needs `clockwise: false` (I think SwiftUI is quirky with clockwise, but you can find the explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57226474/6257435)

Here's your code with those modifications:

```
struct MyShape : Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        
        return Path { path in
            path.move(to: .zero)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 48, y: 0))

            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 48, y: 10),
                        radius: 10,
                        startAngle: .degrees(-90),
                        endAngle: .degrees(0),
                        clockwise: false)

            // need to subtract an additional 10-points
            //  for the 10-point radius
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 + (48 - 10), y: 10),
                          control1: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 80, y: 105),
                          control2: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 + 80, y: 105))

            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 + 48, y: 10),
                        radius: 10,
                        startAngle: .degrees(-180),
                        endAngle: .degrees(-90),
                        clockwise: false)

            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 100))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100))
            path.addLine(to: .zero)
            path.closeSubpath()
        }

    }
    
}
```

and we get this:

[image]

You can get a bit smoother of a curve if you use the `.addArc(tangent1End:tangent2End:radius:)` format:

```
struct MyShape2 : Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        
        return Path { path in
            path.move(to: .zero)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 48, y: 0))
            
            var pt1: CGPoint = .zero
            var pt2: CGPoint = .zero
            
            pt1 = .init(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 48 + 10, y: 0)
            pt2 = .init(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 48 - 10, y: 105)
            path.addArc(tangent1End: pt1, tangent2End: pt2, radius: 10)
            
            let p3 = path.currentPoint!
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - p3.x, y: p3.y),
                          control1: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 80, y: 105),
                          control2: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 + 80, y: 105))
            
            pt1 = .init(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 + 48 - 10, y: 0)
            pt2 = .init(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 + 48 + 10, y: 0)
            path.addArc(tangent1End: pt1, tangent2End: pt2, radius: 10)
            
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 100))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100))
            path.addLine(to: .zero)
            path.closeSubpath()
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

which gives us this result:

[image]

Comment: It was a bit difficult to understand because it's 1 of my first Paths, thank you very much!